# validate model depending radio button selected

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have install yii-user extension and add some column in tbl_profile table for registration. Registration type are two type: Personal and company

**following are the column added:**

**For company**: company_name, comoany_type

**For personal**: phone

**For both personal and company**:  mobile, fullname, country, states, postal_code, address1, address2

I have use jquery to hide and disable the input field of form according to radio button selection of registration type.

Same goes for country selection for both registration type. Two Options: e.g USA and other country

I am confused that how can I validate the property according to the registration type selected. e.g. If I select the personal then disable the validation for the company property field.

There are two models with their property:

**Profile**:  fullname, company_name, company_type, mobile, phone, firstaddress, secondaddress, country, states, postal_code

**RegistrationForm**: username, password, email

I have also define rules for those property on corresponding model.

I have tried validating model like this but doesn't works:

```
if(isset($_POST['RegistrationForm'])) {
    if($_POST['Profile']['account_type'] == 'personal')
    {
        //for personal account
        $profile->account_type = $_POST['Profile']['account_type'];
        $model->username = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['username'];
        $model->password = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['password'];
        $model->verifyPassword = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['verifyPassword'];
        $model->email = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['email'];
        $model->verifyCode = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['verifyCode'];
        $model->accept = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['accept'];
        $profile->fullname = $_POST['Profile']['fullname'];
        $profile->phone = $_POST['Profile']['phone'];
        $profile->ext = $_POST['Profile']['ext'];
        $profile->mobile = $_POST['Profile']['mobile'];
        if($_POST['choose_country'] == 'other')
        {
            $profile->country = $_POST['choose_country'];
            $profile->states = $_POST['profile_states'];
            $profile->postalcode = $_POST['Profile']['postalcode'];
            $profile->firstaddress = $_POST['Profile']['firstaddress'];
            $profile->secondaddress = $_POST['Profile']['secondaddress'];
        }
        if($_POST['choose_country'] == 'Nepal')
        {
            $profile->country = $_POST['choose_country'];
            $profile->firstaddress = $_POST['Profile']['firstaddress'];
            $profile->secondaddress = $_POST['Profile']['secondaddress'];
        }
    }
    if($_POST['Profile']['account_type'] == 'company')
    {
        //for organization account
        $profile->account_type = $_POST['Profile']['account_type'];
        $model->username = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['username'];
        $model->password = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['password'];
        $model->verifyPassword = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['verifyPassword'];
        $model->email = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['email'];
        $model->verifyCode = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['verifyCode'];
        $model->accept = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['accept'];
        $profile->fullname = $_POST['Profile']['fullname'];
        $profile->ext = $_POST['profile']['ext'];
        $profile->mobile = $_POST['Profile']['mobile'];
        $profile->company_name = $_POST['Profile']['company_name'];
        $profile->company_type = $_POST['Profile']['company_type'];
        $profile->designation = $_POST['Profile']['designation'];

        if($_POST['choose_country'] == 'Nepal')
        {
            $profile->country = $_POST['choose_country'];
            $profile->states = $_POST['Profile']['states'];
            $profile->postalcode = $_POST['Profile']['postalcode'];
            $profile->firstaddress = $_POST['profile']['firstaddress'];
            $profile->secondaddress = $_POST['profile']['secondaddress'];
        }
        if($_POST['choose_country'] == 'others')
        {
            $profile->country = $_POST['profile']['country'];
            $profile->firstaddress = $_POST['profile']['firstaddress'];
            $profile->secondaddress = $_POST['profile']['secondaddress'];
        }
    }

    //$model->attributes=$_POST['RegistrationForm'];
    //$profile->attributes=((isset($_POST['Profile'])?$_POST['Profile']:array()));

    if($model->validate()&&$profile->validate())
    {
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

If I select the personal radio button and submit form it still validate the company_name , company type and same for country selection then shows the validation errors. Here what I want is to disable the validation of model depending on selection of radio button either personal or company type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never worked with `yii-user` extension but as a solution I can propose to restrict company and personal validations by setting different [scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/) for your `$profile` model depending on `$_POST['Profile']['account_type']` just before assigning values to model from `$_POST`, e.g.:

```
if ($_POST['Profile']['account_type'] === "personal")
    $profile->scenario = "personal";
else
    $profile->scenario = "company";
```

After that in `rules()` method of your `Profile` model you specify corresponding scenario for each account type dependent field:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        // ...general rules
        array("company_name", "validateCompanyName", 'on' => array("company")),
        array("company_type", "validateCompanyType", 'on' => array("company")),
        array("phone", "validatePersonalPhone", 'on' => array("personal"))
    )
}
```

I believe that this way it will be enough to assign values to models like this:

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['RegistrationForm'];
$profile->attributes = $_POST['Profile'];
```

Comment: what is validateCompanyName, validateCompanyType, ValidatePersonalPhone. We need to defined this rules? or how it is specify

Comment: These are names of possible [custom validation methods](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/) declared in your `Profile` model. You can use [predefined validation rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/) instead if they are suitable for you.

Comment: I would not recommend using scenarios for this, because you can not use the `update` and `insert` scenarios anymore which are used a lot throughout Yii. Just write a custom validation function which validates based on the registrationType property. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/ Make sure you check out http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#securing-attribute-assignments

Comment: @i.amniels: What's wrong with using custom scenarios? Can you show any real example when changing default scenario will affect some useful functionality? If you want to restrict personal profile's insert and update cases you can set `personalUpdate` scenario if `$profile` is retrieved from database and `personalInsert` scenario if it's created using `new` operator.

Comment: what if I want to use more than one scenario e.g. in my case I have registration type and another is country type. For country type can add one more scenario , I have tried validation doesn't works. If it is possible what's the way

Comment: I'm not sure that I got you right but if you want to use a validation rule for more than one scenario you can put names of all these scenarios at `on` array of the rule. If no scenarios are specified for validation rule then this rule will be applied to any scenario.